# How can I find the relationship between dimension and fact tables when there is no FK?

Tags: sql, db2

I need to create a bus matrix and in order to do that i need to know which fact table has relationships with which dimension tables.
Unfortunately, in this new project I'm in, it seems to be no FK (crazy, i know).
What I thought about is to use ETL queries and check the joins between the Fact table with the dimension tables.
What I'm worried about is that there might be more relationships that are not included in ETL queries...any advice?

Comment: If the column names are standardized i.e. using the same name in dimension and fact, the you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view in SQL Server and try to figure out relationship manually.

Comment: @CleanBold unfortunately I'm working with DB2 and don't have that..

Comment: SYSCAT.COLUMNS in DB2

Comment: Check in the company, there may be a logical data model containing this information, or such details can sometimes be reverse engineered if there is a naming convention that is enforced.

Comment: @CleanBold thank you for you answer. How could i figure out the relationship manually? Sorry if it's a silly question, i dont have much experience in data modelling :)

Comment: @mao that's what are trying to do, to reverse engineer what has been implemented as we have no proper documentation. No data model artefacts, nothing

Comment: Somebody has such artefacts, although you may not have them. The question is, what is it worth to find them, or buy them, versus reverse engineering with the associated uncertainties?  This is hardly a matter for stackoverflow, i.e lost artefacts and reverse engineering.

Comment: @mao we have a difficult situation so even if there are such artefacts, most likely we wont have them. That's why we choose to reverse engineer as most likely it will be faster than trying to get those artefact :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system metadata tables to list the foreign key references:

```
select tbname, pkcolnames, reftbname, fkcolnames, colcount
from SYSIBM.SYSRELS B;
```

If the database does not have properly declared foreign key relationships, then the database does not have the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DB holds no information about the FKs (or information that would help you derive them, like identical column names) then, as you mentioned, examining the ETL code used to load each fact table is probably the only other way of doing this. The ETL must be running a look up on each dimension to get the PK to insert into the fact record, so the information will be there.

There shouldn't be any relationships involving facts that you couldn't determine with this approach. There may be additional relationships between dimensions (bridge tables, more complex SCD types, etc.) but if you sorted out the fact relationships then what remains should be a small enough subset to resolve manually (i.e. by intelligent guesswork)